# コピーされたスプレッドシートでも保護設定を引き継ぎたい

Tags: google-apps-script

スプレッドシートの標準機能では下記③のことができず とても困っています。
解決策をアドバイスを頂けたら幸いです。（事情があり急いでいます。）

①google スプレッドシートに保護をかける（特定セルのみ編集可能）
②保護をかけたスプレッドシートをgoogleclassroomで配付（配付オプション：コピーして配付）
③**コピーされたスプレッドシートでも、もとの保護設定を有効にしておきたい**

(詳細追加)
・保護設定は、スプレッドシート作成者のみが編集可能
・Googleclassroomで配付（配付オプション：コピーして配付　するので自動的にコピーが配付されます）
・配付された側は『「特定のセル」のみ編集（入力）可』 。この保護設定を配付された側が「コピーして利用」しても引き継ぎたいです

Comment: こんな記事があるようです。何か参考になれば。[【質問】保護済のスプレッドシートのファイルをコピーすると、コピーされたファイルにその保護が反映されない…？](https://www.facebook.com/groups/google4education.jp/posts/3105864882958426/), [#23 シートを複製して保護する（Google スプレッドシート）](https://note.com/tomo_saka/n/ne2bc0ab3a18c)

Comment: 詳細化された新しい要件は、コメントではなく記事本文を編集して追加してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
参考方法よさそうなので早速試してみました。
保護設定は引き継がれたのですが、編集可能者に　配付されたユーザも追加されてしまいました。

Comment: 英語で恐縮ですが、こちらのサンプルはお役に立てますか？ https://tanaikech.github.io/2021/03/26/copying-protections-for-spreadsheet-using-google-apps-script/

Comment: ありがとうございます。この方法も今後使えそうです。
宛先IDが必要なので（こちらが業務で実行したい）不特定多数に利用してもらう時には無理ですね。

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。`宛先IDが必要なので（こちらが業務で実行したい）不特定多数に利用してもらう時には無理ですね。`の意味が分かりませんでした。申し訳ありません。詳細をお教えいただけないでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。詳細にお伝えしていなくてすみません。google classroomを利用して生徒にファイルを配付します。その際　生徒が個人利用できるよう　配付のオプションで　コピーして利用(自動的コピーが作成される　機能)を設定して配付します。 なので　生徒一人ひとりにそれぞれファイルが作成されます。宛先idはこの作成されたファイルのことだと思っているのですが、自分の知識不足で違っているかもしれません。違っていたらぜひお教えいただきたいです。　また説明させていただいた状況下で保護の有効化の継承の方法のアドバイスお願いします